Metaprop not producing confidence intervals for I2
I have run two meta-analyses on proportions using metaprop in meta package in R. The model was exactly the same (obviously with different data read in).
m1 <-metaprop(event=n,
n=n_total,
studlab=breed,
data=df,
method='GLMM',
sm='PLOGIT',
fixed=FALSE,
random=TRUE,
hakn=TRUE)

In both cases, I had a high degree of heterogeneity of variance. Annoyingly,the format of the output is slightly different - specifically, one analysis did not give the confidence intervals for I2 or H.
First analysis' output:

Second analysis' output:

I presume this is because of extremely high values of I and H, but, is there a reference for this where I could read more?
